# How to render state in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-state

I am a `backend` Python developer. But I need to make a simple `front` on the `React`. I send a `request`, I get a `response`, but I can’t get the `state` out.

```
class AppsList extends Component {
        state = {
            apps: []
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/apps')
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                apps: response.data
            })
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                aaa
                <p>{this.state.apps}</p>
                aaa
            </div>
        );
     }
}
```

**Response**

[image]

Comment: Added response to answer

Comment: I don't know if it'll change something but maybe you can define `this.state` in a constructor (check this doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is not in arrow notation.

You can simply do:

```
.then(response => this.setState({ apps: response.data }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to identify "this" out of the promise and map on this.state.apps like this:

```
class AppsList extends Component {
        state = {
            apps: []
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {setState} = this;
        axios.get('/apps')
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            setState({
                apps: response.data
            })
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                aaa
                <div>
                  {this.state.apps.map((app) => {
                    return (<p key={app.id}>{app.name}</p>)
                  })}
                </div>
                aaa
            </div>
        );
     }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit on the answer. Recheck on it please!

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
class AppsList extends Component {
    state = {
        apps: []
    }

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/apps')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            apps: response.data
        })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            aaa
            <p>{this.state.apps.map(elem => <div>{elem.id} {elem.name}</div>)}</p>
            aaa
        </div>
    );
 }
}
```